# How can I configure folder/file views in 12.04.4?

Tags: gnome

I would like to set up my user account folder view options to show as much information as `ls -a` does in a terminal window.

Is this possible? And how? If not, how close can I get?

Comment: You can go to Nautilus->Edit->Preferences->Display tab and under Icons caption use may choose to display file size or etc

Answer (score 0):

`ls -a` is used to list files starting with an `.` (dot) which are hidden files. So, you want to view also the hidden files in your file manager.

In **Nautilus**, the default file manager in Ubuntu, you can view hidden files by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

To make the change permanently, you need to enable **Show hidden and backup files** from **Files** → **Preferences**, **Views** tab:

[image: Show hidden and backup files]